# Query to display largest n% of values and group the rest as "other"

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I see someone posted something very similar to what I am looking to do in Access 2010.

[Grouping of top 80% categories](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17971643)

I saw the response but am confused as to the nomenclature used and the titles assigned. I have 5 vendors that supply product. I only care about the top 80% as a pareto distribution and the remainder can be grouped as "Other"

4 vendors as Field [vendors]: A1, A2, A3, A4

4 values as Field [Lbs]: 4000, 5000, 200, 800

Query returns: A1, A2, Other

Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 2):

When performing calculations like this we need to be mindful of what happens when there is a tie, so let's use the following [VendorData]

```
vendors  lbs 
-------  ----
A1       2000
A2       3000
A3        200
A4        800
A5       2000
A6       2000
```

We can start by creating the following saved query named [VendorPct] in Access

```sql
SELECT 
    vendors, 
    lbs, 
    lbs_sum,
    lbs / lbs_sum * 100 AS lbs_pct
FROM
    (
        SELECT vendors, lbs, lbs_sum
        FROM
            VendorData,
            (
                SELECT Sum(lbs) AS lbs_sum FROM VendorData
            )
    )
```

It gives us

```
vendors  lbs   lbs_sum  lbs_pct
-------  ----  -------  -------
A1       2000    10000       20
A2       3000    10000       30
A3        200    10000        2
A4        800    10000        8
A5       2000    10000       20
A6       2000    10000       20
```

Now we can create a saved query in Access named [VendorPctCumulative]

```sql
SELECT 
    vendors, 
    Max(lbs) AS lbs_, 
    Max(lbs_pct) as lbs_pct_, 
    Sum(lbs_pct_other) AS lbs_pct_cumulative_
FROM
    (
            SELECT 
                vendors, 
                lbs, 
                lbs_pct, 
                lbs_pct AS lbs_pct_other 
            FROM VendorPct
        UNION ALL
            (
                SELECT 
                    v1.vendors, 
                    v1.lbs,
                    v1.lbs_pct,
                    v2.lbs_pct AS lbs_pct_other 
                FROM
                    VendorPct v1
                    INNER JOIN
                    VendorPct v2
                        ON (v2.lbs = v1.lbs AND v2.vendors < v1.vendors)
                            OR v2.lbs > v1.lbs
            )
    )
GROUP BY vendors
ORDER BY Sum(lbs_pct_other), vendors
```

That produces

```
vendors  lbs_  lbs_pct_  lbs_pct_cumulative_
-------  ----  --------  -------------------
A2       3000        30                   30
A1       2000        20                   50
A5       2000        20                   70
A6       2000        20                   90
A4        800         8                   98
A3        200         2                  100
```

Now one more saved query named [VendorPctCumulativeThreshold] to find the first cumulative percent that meets or exceeds the 80% threshold:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 lbs_pct_cumulative_ 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT lbs_pct_cumulative_ 
        FROM VendorPctCumulative
        WHERE lbs_pct_cumulative_ >= 80
        ORDER BY lbs_pct_cumulative_
    )
```

i.e.,

```
lbs_pct_cumulative_
-------------------
                 90
```

and we can put it all together with

```sql
    SELECT 
        vendors, 
        lbs_ AS lbs, 
        lbs_pct_ AS lbs_pct
    FROM
        VendorPctCumulative vpc
        INNER JOIN
        VendorPctCumulativeThreshold vpct
            ON vpc.lbs_pct_cumulative_ <= vpct.lbs_pct_cumulative_
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        "other" AS vendors, 
        Sum(lbs_) AS lbs, 
        Sum(lbs_pct_) AS lbs_pct
    FROM
        VendorPctCumulative vpc
        INNER JOIN
        VendorPctCumulativeThreshold vpct
            ON vpc.lbs_pct_cumulative_ > vpct.lbs_pct_cumulative_
ORDER BY 3 DESC, 1
```

producing

```
vendors  lbs   lbs_pct
-------  ----  -------
A2       3000       30
A1       2000       20
A5       2000       20
A6       2000       20
other    1000       10
```

Comment: How is `SELECT Sum(lbs) AS lbs_sum FROM VendorData` joined in the VendorPct query?  I'm trying to include this as a subquery, but I can't see how I'd join it in.

Comment: @TrevorD It isn't joined. It is the sum of [lbs] over all the records and because there is no explicit join between it and [VendorData] it appears in each row of the result. (Omitting an explicit JOIN condition between two "tables" results in a [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join).)