# How to combine bottom "x" percent of values?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query to create a Pareto chart with downtime bucketed data.  There are 15-20 buckets, but the bottom 5 or so are insignificant enough they should be grouped together.  This is in Access, so I'm looking for a sustainable query that can take the bottom 3% of values (or 5%, whatever) and group them with a new `job_code_desc` like "Other".  Here is my query

```
SELECT 
original.job_code_desc, 
sum(original.sumofdowntime) AS SumOfDowntime

FROM 
(SELECT IIF(pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc like "*RP*","HI-LO WORK",pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc) AS job_code_desc, Round(Sum([pareto_downtime_detail_tbl].[downtime]),2) AS SumOfdowntime
FROM pareto_downtime_detail_tbl
WHERE (((pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.position_desc) Like '*selector*'))
GROUP BY pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc
HAVING (((pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc) Not Like 'break' And (pareto_downtime_detail_tbl.job_code_desc) Not Like '*prep*'))
ORDER BY Round(Sum([pareto_downtime_detail_tbl].[downtime]),2) DESC)  AS original

GROUP BY 
original.job_code_desc

ORDER BY 
sum(original.sumofdowntime) DESC;
```

And I get results like

```
job_code_desc   SumOfDowntime
D2S ONHOLD  1653.85
IWHSUPPORT  1278.62
D2S LOAD    701.13
LIGHT DUTY  693.24
BATT0001    567.52
D2S MAINT   457.13
D2S NOWORK  386.89
D2S SPPROJ  272.12
HI-LO WORK  212.06
D2S TRAIN   126.91
D2S MEET    95.77
MANAGER 83.78
D2S UNLO    73.59
D2S CLEAN   65.34
D2S SYSDWN  65.13
REC-FORK    25.7
D2S_DISTRO  4.95
TWR SYSDWN  3.99
REC-REJECT  1.08
SEL-TIER    0.25
SEL-CASE    0.09
ACP CLEAN   0.02
```

So I just want to take the values D2S_DISTRO and below and sum the values to the 10.13 with the title "Other".  I really don't know how to go about this.

Comment: Edit your question with the actual operation in pseudo code,its not very clear what you want.

Comment: There is an answer to a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19926647/2144390).

Comment: Hm, I already have a Pareto query that shows the Cum PCT.  I'll tinker with that and your response in the provided link to see if I can get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, you have the result as above. You can then use a subquery to group your result.

In this example I grouped the result when the SumOfDowntime <= 1, and then name it 'Others'.

```
SELECT tbl.Job_DescGrouped, SUM(tbl.SumOfDowntimeinsert) AS ColumnTest
FROM (
 select *, 
 CASE WHEN SumOfDowntimeinsert > 1 THEN job_desc ELSE 'OTHERS' END AS Job_DescGrouped,
 CASE WHEN SumOfDowntimeinsert > 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS OrderByColumn
 from jobs) tbl
GROUP BY tbl.Job_DescGrouped
ORDER BY OrderByColumn, ColumnTest
```

Full example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd6b1/7)

-- Edit: Sorry, this is SQL no Access. But I hope it might help you.