# Statistical calculations in an Access 2010 query

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

currently we're building a database to track different factories' pollutant emissions. Now a query is needed that gives us information about relative quantities. Somehow I feel this should be straight forward but I have had no success implementing it in SQL.

I'm starting from a working query that returns the following fields:

```
PRODUCTION_YEAR, COMPANY, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, POLLUTANT, TOTAL_EMISSIONS, SHARE
```

TOTAL_EMISSIONS contains the total emissions for each company in a particular year and product category. SHARE is a computed field and contains the contribution (as a fraction) of each company to that year's overall emissions of that particular pollutant in that particular product category.

Now the task is to count the factories contributing to each pollutant. I arrived at this:

```
SELECT PRODUCTION_YEAR, POLLUTANT, PRODUCT_CATEGORY, Count(COMPANY)
  FROM theQuery
  GROUP BY PRODUCTION_YEAR, POLLUTANT, PRODUCT_CATEGORY;
```

However, now our client wants something more sophisticated: count only the biggest polluters who contribute 95% of emissions. In a script, I'd probably just have the pollution percentages in each category sorted ascendingly, then walk the dataset, sum up the shares and only start counting after reaching 5%. Doing it in SQL, no idea.

My first step (adding a SUM(SHARE) field to the new query) already resulted in errors ("expression not included in aggregate function", roughly translated, not sure what to make of it because all the expressions were indeed included). Is there even a way to do this in an SQL query, or am I wasting my time and would be better off just writing some VBA?

Thanks for any input!

Best,
Ben

Comment: A while back I answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19918495/2144390). Does that help?

Comment: Thank you Gord, that looks amazing. It's quite complex and I'll need some time to look at it, but I think it is exactly what I need!

Comment: Thanks again, your method works perfectly! It does bring Access to its knees though - running the full query, which includes a few aggregates, typically results in an instant crash. Running the saved queries step by step is safer. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gord's method (see link in comment) works well for this task.